# IE CSS behaves in a weird way

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

When I view the cart of my website in Firefox the 'total' is in exactly the same place where it should be, but when I view it in IE 8 it is 60-80px below when the page is loaded. As soon as the mouse is clicked on the page the 'total' goes back to where it should be.

Why is this happening?

Is it the issue with CSS?

Comment: Welcome to web-development and Internet Explorer

Comment: Please post your code. It is hard to help without knowing what you are doing.

Comment: here is the css .`bill_info table tbody tr.total td, table tbody tr.total td { font-size:20px; padding:3px; text-align:right; }`

Answer (score 0):

Some example markup would be helpful, but...

Make sure you're specifying a [doctype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctype) in your markup, and that it is the first line of your HTML. Otherwise, IE will render in [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).

Comment: Yup doctype is mentioned in my markup.

and here is the css .`bill_info table tbody tr.total td, table tbody tr.total td {
 font-size:20px;
 padding:3px;
 text-align:right;
}`

Answer (score 0):

If some of the elements in the page are generated by javascript or otherwise modified by javascript, I've noticed (especially in IE7 and older) that the DOM model and the actual screen repaint is sometimes out of synch and does not update unless you move the cursor above the incorrect part. Unfortunately I've found no foolproof workaround. Sometimes though, adding and immediately removing an element into the dom somewhere, can cause the page to repaint...

Debugging IE sure is fun! ;P